# C# STARTUPINFO Flags to show UI for a process started from a Service in XP

Tags: c#

I'm launching a process from a windows service in XP, I'm just launching the process not trying to interact with it. The process starts but the UI does not show. I believe I need to set some flags in STARTUPINFO to make process visible, and hoping someone could show how and what flags to set.

```
    sPath = @"C:\Windows\notepad.exe";

    string Message = string.Empty;

    // Variables
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    STARTUPINFO startInfo = new STARTUPINFO();

    Boolean bResult = false;
    IntPtr hToken = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        // Logon user
        bResult = LogonUser(
            "Test",
            "VirtualXP-23639",
            "test",
            LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
            LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
            out hToken
        );
        if (!bResult) { throw new Exception("Logon error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); }

        // Create process
        startInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(startInfo);
        startInfo.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";

        bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(
            hToken,
            null,
            sPath,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            false,
            0,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            null,
            ref startInfo,
            out processInfo
        );

        if (!bResult)
        {
            Message = "Failed to Create Process on Desktop/Console.  Code=" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString();
            Logging.LogError(Ascension.CM.Common.Enums.ApplicationModuleEnums.Service, Message, "Ascension.CM.ServiceWorker.ProcessLauncher.XpLaunchDesktopProcess", null);
        }


    }
    finally
    {
        // Close all handles
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, but I've found a solution.

I ended up using WTSQueryUserToken to get the current logged in user and then used DuplicateTokenEx to get a token that I used with CreateProcessAsUser to start the process.

For XP use session id 0 and for win7 use WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId to get the current session Id.

This works fine with out having to use the "Allow to interact with Desktop" property.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll at least need to allow the service to interact with the desktop, so in services.msc, click on your serivce an go to properties, then logon and select allow to interact with desktop..

Comment: This is exactly right. I just coded something like this last night and was having the same issue until I realized that I needed to enable this option!

Comment: This is not the greatest advice. Services should not be allowed to interact with desktop. And of course this approach fails horrible on Vista up with session 0 isolation.

Comment: I've already set the "Allow to interact with Desktop" property, but the UI still does not show. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct it wont work in vista or higher. But he does ask specifically for windows XP. Hes not trying to interact with it just display the UI. The question I suppose then becomes why do you need to see the UI? If its just for confirmation that something is happening a log file would be a better options with a redirected output..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the Process class in the .net framework.

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe")
```

This should have your desired effect.